# find out the elements of an arraylist which is not present in another arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections, arraylist

I have to find a best way to find out that elements which is not presented in the second arraylist. 
suppose

```
Arraylist a,b, 

Arraylist a={1,2,3,4,5};
Arraylist b={2,3,4};
```

So basically what I want is to find out that elements of **a** which is not present in **arraylist b**.

So what is the best solutions to do that?

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk are the input arrays sorted by any means?

Comment: thanks for asking this question. I was asked this question today in an interview, although I was not able to answer it then, but its good to know the answer finally.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

```
List<Integer> c = new ArrayList<>(a);
c.removeAll(b);
```

Also consider to use Sets instead of Lists.

Comment: Be careful! removeAll() use equals() to compare elements. Therefore, you may not get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 20):

here is another approach using java 8 -

```
a.stream().filter(b::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I'd love this answer if it was more elaborated. For example, as @NamHoang says in another answer, this would use your `equals` method. Besides that, +1 for introducing new concepts in an old question.

Comment: This will find all items in a that exist in b, the question about finding items in a does NOT exist in b.

Comment: @Al-Mothafar `a.stream().filter(element -> !b.contains(element)).collect(Collectors.toList());`...

Answer (score 15):

You could use [Apache Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/), which has a method explicitly for this purpose:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
    List<Integer> b = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 2, 3, 4 });
    Collection<Integer> aMinusB = CollectionUtils.subtract(a, b);
    System.out.println(aMinusB);
}
```

The printed result is: *[1, 5]*.

The Apache Commons libs are well tested and commonly used to extend standard Java functionalities. This particular method accepts `Iterable` as parameters, so you can use any `Collection` you want. You can also mix different collection types:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
    Set<Integer> b = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 2, 3, 4 }));
    Collection<Integer> aMinusB = CollectionUtils.subtract(a, b);
    System.out.println(aMinusB);
}
```

The printed result is the same, *[1, 5]*.

Check out the Javadoc [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#subtract-java.lang.Iterable-java.lang.Iterable-).

---

For sake of completeness, Google's [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library [does not have this feature](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ApacheCommonCollectionsEquivalents):

> `Collection *subtract*(Collection, Collection)`
> No equivalent--create an ArrayList containing a and then call remove on it for each element in b.

However, it implements a method called [`Sets.difference()`](https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release04/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#difference%28java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set%29) method, which you could use if you prefer Guava and work with sets:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Integer> a = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }));
    Set<Integer> b = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 2, 3, 4 }));
    Set<Integer> aMinusB = Sets.difference(a, b);
    System.out.println(aMinusB);
}
```

The result is all elements in `a` that doesn't exist in `b` (i.e. *[1, 5]* again). Of course, the order is not determined since it operates on sets.

Answer (score 12):

You can try `removeAll`:

```
List<Integer> notPresent = new ArrayList<Integer>(a);
notPresent.removeAll(b);
```

Comment: - Uses generics parameter not raw type - removeAll returns a boolean not a List

Comment: this would be not a good practice, is there any kind of method which can sort and search automatically

Comment: As @Puce pointed, you better use sets instead of lists. They are faster for this kind of operations.

Comment: what if I use Hashset ,like this

    hashset h;
    
    h.add(a);
    h.add(b);

 
then iterate through this set

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk if you need to keep all numbers sorted you can use TreeSet.

Answer (score 10):

Use `org.apache.commons.collections4.ListUtils`

**Given**

```
List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{  1,2,3,4,5});
List<Integer> b = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{0,1,2,3});
```

**Action**

```
List<Integer> c = ListUtils.removeAll(b, a)
```

**Result in List c**

```
4, 5
```

Comment: Although you've dug up a four-year-old question, it's interesting to compare your solution, using Apache ListUtils, with Magnilex's solution using Apache CollectionUtils. Although they appear to do the same thing, their behaviour is subtly different - see their documentation.

Comment: i love that someone thought of the complete problem and made b have elements not present in a. thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

Please try like this

```
for (Object o : a) {  
  if (!b.contains(o)) {  
    // this is not present
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through one list, then check if each element in other list using [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this. If you think there may be duplicates in `a` you can try another type of `Collection`, like a `Set` for `notPresent`.

```
   List<Integer> notPresent = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (Integer n : a){
     if (!b.contains(n)){
       notPresent.add(n);
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> exclusion = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        a.add(1);
        a.add(2);
        a.add(3);
        a.add(4);

        b.add(1);
        b.add(2);
        b.add(3);
        b.add(5);

        for (Integer x : a) {
            if (!b.contains(x)) {
                exclusion.add(x);
            }
        }

        for (Integer x : exclusion) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Use the `contains()` method of List.

```
ArrayList<Integer> aList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (Integer i : a){

      if (!(b.contains(i))){

             aList.add(i);

       }

     else{
             continue;

      }

 }
```