# Compare 2 list with different object java return unmatched list

Tags: java

How to compare 2 list
ArrayList with List

ArrayList list = {a,b,c,d}
and
List lst = {a,b,c,d,e}

result:
List al = {e}

How should I approach this problem?
As Objects are different the comparator does not work, even set or other operation will not work

```
    List<String> al = null;
    Map<String, List<String>> tagMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    for (TkMGroup anotherTest : lst) {
        String id = anotherTest.getGrpCd();
        for (CsvGroup tag : list) {
            if (id.equals(tag.getGrpCd())) {
                if (tagMap.containsKey(id)) { // is this `id` already populated?
                    al = tagMap.get(id);
                } else { // No! Create a new List.
                    al = new ArrayList<String>();
                    tagMap.put(id, al);
                }
                // Add the tag to the List.
                al.add(tag.getGrpCd());
            } else {
                //              al.add(id);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(al.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: No comparing instance will always return false and unmatched element won't be fetched from list? Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find out the elements of an arraylist which is not present in another arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286008/find-out-the-elements-of-an-arraylist-which-is-not-present-in-another-arraylist)

Comment: ThankYou @Tarmo but I have 2 list with different object so that won't work.

Comment: How about you add a common superclass to the objects which has the property that you want to compare. Then you can build a comparator on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand what `tagMap` was used for.
My solution fill `al` (provided) with the intersection of `groups` (provided as `lst`) and `csvs` (provided as `list`)

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class TkMGroup {
    private String id;

    public TkMGroup(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getGrpCd() {
        return this.id;
    }
}

class CsvGroup {
    private String id;

    public CsvGroup(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getGrpCd() {
        return this.id;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> al = null;

        List<TkMGroup> groups = new ArrayList<>();
        groups.add(new TkMGroup("One"));
        groups.add(new TkMGroup("Two"));

        List<CsvGroup> csvs = new ArrayList<>();
        csvs.add(new CsvGroup("One"));
        csvs.add(new CsvGroup("Three"));

        // Get lists of Ids
        List<String> groupIds = groups.stream().map(TkMGroup::getGrpCd).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<String> csvIds = csvs.stream().map(CsvGroup::getGrpCd).collect(Collectors.toList());
        // Filter intersection
        al = groupIds.stream().filter(csvIds::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());
        // Print the result
        for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(al.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 1 : Listing each CSV which has no existing group listed.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class TkMGroup {
    private String id;

    public TkMGroup(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getGrpCd() {
        return this.id;
    }
}

class CsvGroup {
    private String id;

    public CsvGroup(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getGrpCd() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CsvGroup{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<CsvGroup> al = null;

        List<TkMGroup> groups = new ArrayList<>();
        groups.add(new TkMGroup("One"));
        groups.add(new TkMGroup("Two"));

        List<CsvGroup> csvs = new ArrayList<>();
        csvs.add(new CsvGroup("One"));
        csvs.add(new CsvGroup("Three"));

        // Get list of group's id
        List<String> groupIds = groups.stream().map(TkMGroup::getGrpCd).collect(Collectors.toList());

        // Filter out intersection
        al = csvs.stream().filter(csv -> ! groupIds.contains(csv.getGrpCd())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        // You need to access csv.getGrpCd() to check that the group is not already listed

        // Print the result
        for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(al.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the solution @IQbrod , Do not Filter on intersection instead we need to get the data that is not present in another list. This returns all the values that are present. This will work though with little modification.

Comment: @shweta you might replace the comparison in filter like `.filter(groupId -> ! csvIds.contains(groupId))` to get each groupId not contained in csvIds.

Comment: @shweta if you need each csvId not present in groupIds you might switch both idList like `al = csvIds.stream().filter(csvId -> ! groupIds.contains(csvId)).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Yes this is exact solution :)

Comment: Just wondering what if I need whole List<object> based on al.get(i) value? Is this possible?

Comment: @shweta here you go :)

Answer (score -1):

List and ArrayList are the members of the Collection framework. The list is a collection of elements in a sequence where each element is an object and elements are accessed by their position (index). ArrayList creates a dynamic array of objects that increases or reduces in size whenever required. The primary difference between List and ArrayList is that List is an interface and ArrayList is a class.

**Key Differences Between List and ArrayList**

- One of the most important differences between List and ArrayList is that list is an interface and ArrayList is a standard Collection class.
- List interface extends the Collection framework whereas, the ArrayList extends
  AbstractList Class and it implements Listinterfaces.
- The namespace for List interface System.Collection.Generic whereas, the namespace for ArrayList is System.Collection.
- List interface creates a collection of elements that are stored in a sequence and are identified or accessed by their index number.
- On the other hand, ArrayList creates an array of objects where the array can dynamically grow when required.

Example-

```
        import java.util.*;  
        public class ComapreArraylistandList  
        {  
        public static void main(String args[])  
        {  
          
        ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();   
        al.add("A");  
        al.add("B");  
        al.add("C");  
        al.add("D");  
        System.out.println(al);  
        
        List<String> sl=new ArrayList<String>();  
        sl.add("A");  
        sl.add("B");  
        sl.add("C");  
        sl.add("D");  
        System.out.println(sl);  
        
        //comparing both lists  
        boolean bval = al.equals(sl); //returns true because lists are equal  
        System.out.println(bval);  
        }  
        }
```

Comment: here, objects are same so might return true, but when the objects are different it fails while comparing